# Error when trying to upload file to Azure File Share

Tags: c#, xml, azure, file-upload

I'm trying to upload an xml file to a Azure File Share in a Storage account, but i keep getting this error:

**The range specified is invalid for the current size of the resource.**

*I am able to download files from the same share, so the connection itself works*

I have created a xml file which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<WebOrderList xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <WebOrder>
    <OrderId>1</OrderId>
    <Info>info about order</Info>
    <Description>testing</Description>
    <WebItemListWebItem>
      <ItemNo>321</ItemNo>
      <ParentID>0</ParentID>
    </WebItemListWebItem>
  </WebOrder>
</WebOrderList>
```

The method uploading the content looks like this:

```
public async Task UploadFile(string content, string path, string name)
{
    var fileClient = new ShareFileClient(_connectionString, _shareName, path);
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content);
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
    {
         await fileClient.UploadAsync(stream);
    }
}
```

where content is the xml string above, path is /orders/fromwebshop which is an existing folder on the file share, and name is order-1.xml.

**Error:**

Windows-Azure-File/1.0,Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0

x-ms-error-code: InvalidRange

Date: Thu, 24 Sep 2020 06:39:39 GMT

Content-Length: 249

Content-Type: application/xml

**UPDATE:
I found out that this works:**
[image]

If you want to copy:

```
  //ExampleData
    //Content = string as Xml.
    //Path = "$"/orders/fromwebshop""
    //Name = "$"order-{order.WebOrder[0].OrderId}.xml"
    public async Task UploadFile(string content, string path, string name)
    {
        var newMove = new ShareFileClient(_connectionString, _shareName, $"{path}/{name}");
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content);
        await newMove.CreateAsync(byteArray.Length);
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
        {
            await newMove.UploadAsync(stream);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The error message indicate the server has a size limit.  You may want to zip the file before uploading to reduce the size.  You can add : .setContentEncoding("gzip").  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.storage.file.share.sharefileclient.createwithresponse?view=azure-java-stable

Comment: Its 249 bytes. Cant be it? :D

Comment: The content type is wrong.  You are uploading a file and the data in the file doesn't matter.  Where in your code are you specifying XML?

Comment: I guess it sees it from the name? I think i found the error though. I cant use UploadAsync before CreateAsync it seems. But createAsync needs a "maxsize" in the method. I guess the bytearray.length is the correct size

Comment: An upload has a file source and file destination are filenames. Not sure why you have a MemoryStream.

Comment: UploadAsync only takes in a stream. The "file" in this case is just a string with xml data that i need to upload to a ftp share in azure file share.

Comment: I think You got the code working.  I suspect your issue was with the memorystream.  After filling the stream with  data you must move the position to zero before reaing.  So you were missing the line : stream.Position = 0;

Comment: @sindrem Since you have solved the issue by yourself, please post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE:
I found out that this works:**
[image]

If you want to copy the code:

```
  //ExampleData
    //Content = string as Xml.
    //Path = "$"/orders/fromwebshop""
    //Name = "$"order-{order.WebOrder[0].OrderId}.xml"
    public async Task UploadFile(string content, string path, string name)
    {
        var newMove = new ShareFileClient(_connectionString, _shareName, $"{path}/{name}");
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content);
        await newMove.CreateAsync(byteArray.Length);
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
        {
            await newMove.UploadAsync(stream);
        }
    }
```